# How to add utility ldapsearch to yocto image?

Tags: ldap, yocto, openldap

I have successfully added the recipe `openldap` to my yocto-base Linux distribution, by the instruction:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "openldap"
```

After that I've created a `path/to/my-layer/recipes-support/openldap/openldap_%.bbappend` file and put in it the instruction:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped"
```

The previous setting specifies to the Quality Assurance (QA) checks what to skip and in this case  (see [Yocto manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-insane) about `insane.bbclass`) we ask to skip:

> **already-stripped**: Checks that produced binaries have not already been stripped prior to the build system extracting debug symbols. It is common for upstream software projects to default to stripping debug symbols for output binaries. In order for debugging to work on the target using -dbg packages, this stripping must be disabled.

Without the previous instruction the compilation of `openldap` fails with this error:

```
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapcompare' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapdelete' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapexop' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapmodify' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapmodrdn' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldappasswd' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapsearch' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapurl' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/ldapwhoami' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/sbin/slapd' from openldap was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: openldap-2.4.50-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
```

The compilation process produces the binary for the utility `ldapsearch` but this binary isn't installed into the image.
Instead I'm sure that `openldap` results correctly installed into the distribution.

I don't find any method to add `ldapsearch` (and other utilities correctly compiled) to the image.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/openldap_2.4.50.bb` present in my yocto base system build containes many packages and not only the package `openldap`.
One of the other is package is `openldap-bin` and this is the package which adds **ldapsearch** to the image.

So I have changed the assignment to `IMAGE_INSTALL` as below:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "openldap openldap-bin"
```

By this modification my linux distribution contains `ldapsearch` (and other utilities).